# Error installing devstack permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, permission-denied

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nDzX.png)

```
touch: cannot touch '/devstack/.localrc.password': Permission denied
Error on exit
/devstack/tools/worlddump.py:22: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils import spawn
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-12-06-185541.txt for details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/devstack/tools/worlddump.py", line 272, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/devstack/tools/worlddump.py", line 249, in main
    with io.open(fname, 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-12-06-185541.txt'
```

i tried but dont complete. please help me

Comment: Which distro are you using and which openstack version are you trying to install? Which guide are you following, and who does the devstack directory belong to?